# Creating one-time cgroup

Tags: linux, gentoo, systemd, cgroups

I would like to be able to create a one-time temporary group in hierarchy. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
run_with_csubgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/group/subgroup/
```

Which creates group say `/sys/fs/cgroup/group/subgroup/5G7ds/` (5G7ds is one-time name - it might be ID or anything).

I would like to delete the group automatically but I don't know how to do it easily and prone to say TERM signal (from actidental <kbd>C-c</kbd>).

Is there a way to do it?
I'm using Gentoo+systemd.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to create a temporary group?

Comment: @Mathieu: I don't need to create a temporary group but I have a set of tasks which contains various processes (each takes a few minutes to few hours). I want (not need) them to compete in scheduler as a whole rather then as separate processes.

Comment: You can use `trap` to react on signals. Does not solve the question re. cgroups but may help re. capturing `ctrl-c`

Answer (score 3):

You can run your command(s) via `systemd-run --scope`. This creates a transient (ie temporary) cgroup for your command. You can then modify the cgroup to your needs.
Use `systemd-cgls` to find your process in the cgroup hierarchy under `/sys/fs/cgroup`.

According to the [systemd-run manpage](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html)

> systemd-run may be used to create and start a transient .service or a transient .timer or a .scope unit and run the specified COMMAND in it.

You can also specify restrictions for your unit via the `systemd-run` command by using the `--property` flag (more than once is allowed). For available properties you can check with the [sytemd.resource-control manpage](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

If you want to set properties later on, you can use `systemd set-property`.

Keep in mind that it's a good idea to provide a name for your unit with the `--unit=yourname` flag, so you can easily access it.

There is a very good text about [the new control group interface](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/), which I strongly recommend.
Also, the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
Resource Management and Linux Containers Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7-Beta/Resource_Management_and_Linux_Containers_Guide/) provides a very clear description of how to use cgroups wirh systemd.

Comment: If it's about the links: I couldn't add more than two links yet :-)

Comment: In case I got somerhing wrong, I apologize!

Comment: Added the links :-)

Comment: For completeness: You can kill the group with `systemctl stop <scopename>.scope`. If you leave off `.scope` systemctl will append `.service` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify a specific lifetime for your group; you may want it on after computer startup and deleted after shutdown. So it's not a bad idea to add it to your `/etc/rc` scripts .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, but can't you just:

```
~] umount /sys/fs/cgroup/group/subgroup/5G7ds/
~] rmdir /sys/fs/cgroup/group/subgroup/5G7ds/
```

The above unmounts the cgroup and removes it.

Comment: I would like to have it automated. I.e. a group which 'autodestructs' when there is no tasks to it (in similar way as inode is freed after there is no entries pointing to it).

Comment: The easiest solution that comes to mind is just checking whether a tasks file in a given cgroup is empty and if it is, run the above commands. You can set it up as a cron job that executes every 10 minutes and cleans up any "unused" cgroups.